# How to filter JSON values based on key values and remove the duplicate values

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, sorting, filter

I have the following Json

```
var initialdata = [
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "Region": "US",
    "SubRegion": "US-1",
    "SiteID": "234"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point"
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "Region": "US",
    "SubRegion": "US-1",
    "SiteID": "235"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point"
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "Region": "US",
    "SubRegion": "US-2",
    "SiteID": "234"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point"
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "Region": "UK",
    "SubRegion": "UKK",
    "SiteID": "121"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point"
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "Region": "UK",
    "SubRegion": "UKK",
    "SiteID": "121"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point"
  }
}
]
```

I have the dropdown based on the keys of **initialdata.properties**
for example I have the dropdown like below

```
Region
SubRegion
SiteID
```

If user choose **Region** dropdown means, I need the following output as a list for user selection with out duplication

```
US
UK
```

How can I achieve this?

If anyone have any idea please share it with me

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function which will reduce this to an array which you can use for your dropdown.

```
initialData.reduce((prev, cur) => {
     if(!prev.includes(cur.properties.Region)) {
        prev.push(cur.properties.Region)      
}
return prev
}, [])
```

And if instead of region you need another key in properties, you can store that value in the a const and use it in the reduce function.
Ex: `cur.properties[dropdownSelected]`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but its throwing some undefined includes error.
can you please give me one sample based on my code?

Comment: Pls check the code above, I have edited it.